# How to Ommit DataGridViewRow from DataSource Based on Another Table's Data

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView filled with Bills from a DataTable (which is set as it's DataSource). These Bills are shown to my engineers so that they can build a Bill of Materials.

This is the SQL query which gets all my Bills:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Bills
ORDER BY Case IsNumeric(JobNumber) 
WHEN 1 THEN Replicate('0', 50 - Len(JobNumber)) + JobNumber ELSE JobNumber END
```

*This sorts the bills by job number (some are numbers, some are strings and some are a mix of integers and characters).*

---

**Features**

They can open the bill to view it (**Read only**) or to **edit** it.

**Further explanation**

If an engineer opens a Bill to edit it, it will be placed in a table named "OpenBills". I do this so that no other engineer can open the same bill and edit it while being worked on. The point of the OpenBills table is to determine which bill is opened. Once I know which bill is opened, I don't want it to be provided in their DataGridView when they go to edit a bill.

On the other hand, when the engineer searches for a bill to open as read-only, they should ALL be displayed (*even the ones currently opened*). The difference is I simply put a light blue color as the background of the row to notify the user that it is currently opened.

**My current '*solution*'**

I am currently using a `CellFormatting` event on my DataGridview. In short, I verify if the current Bill being added is in my OpenBills table `lst_OpenBills`. If it is, then I verify if I am viewing the DataGridView as read-only or for editting mode. If it's in edit mode, I will hide the row. If it is in read-only, I will change it's back color.

```
Private Sub dgvBills_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvBills.CellFormatting
    Dim drv As DataRowView
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If e.RowIndex <= dsBOM.Tables("dtBills").Rows.Count - 1 Then
            drv = dsBOM.Tables("dtBills").DefaultView.Item(e.RowIndex)
            Dim c As Color
            If lst_OpenBills.ContainsKey(drv.Item("PK_Bill").ToString) Then
                If int_EntryPoint = 0 Then
                    'Read Only
                    c = Color.LightBlue
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = c
                Else
                    'Edit mode
                    dgvBills.Rows(e.RowIndex).Visible = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### Problem with current solution

I use AlternatingRowStyles to make it easier to read. As you can see in the following comparisons, the edit mode picture should not display the alternating row styles like that. How could I ommit the DataGridViewRow from the DataTable ? Should I just re-apply the AlternatingRowStyles?

***Read Only  results***

[image: Read only]

***Edit mode***

[image: Edit mode]

Does anyone have any solutions? Perhaps my query to get all my bills isn't appropriate ... I use the same form for both situations (read-only & edit mode). I just differentiate them using an Enum `enum_EntryPoint`. Any helps or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the datatable and remove the one you have selected and redraw the datagridview.  Not another SQL call just using the datatable you already have.  You can reinsert the row if you want, when done, or just use that same beginning datatable to refresh the DGV.
For example if the open bill was id 1287:

```
Dim dtTemp As DataTable = dtOpenBills.Clone()
For Each dr As DataRow in dtOpenBills.Rows
    If Cint(dr("OpenBillID")) <> 1287  Then
       Dim drTemp As DataRow = dtTemp.NewRow()
       drTemp = dr
       dtTemp.Rows.Add(drTemp)
    End If
Next
DataGridViewName.DataSource = dtTemp
DataGridViewName.Refresh()  'Might not be needed
```

You haven't touched the original datatable.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but I wanted to avoid reiterating through the DataTable (over 10k records) for efficiency. I'll try your solution on Monday in any case. I thought of another solution which just changes the row colors, for example, a red color would mean it is already opened in editting mode.

Comment: The nice thing about using the existing data table is its already in memory, shouldn't slow you down too much.  Let me know how it goes, have a good weekend.